# Hide a form based on referer_url value

Tags: javascript, referrer

I have a small form on my 404 page that I only want to be shown if the visitor comes from a website -- thus if a visitor comes from an email link or directly accesses the URL, then I don't want them to see the form at all.

The reason: this form is about a broken link they have clicked to get to this 404 web page. If they clicked on an email link, or if they just typed the URL, then there's nothing I can correct. So there's no need for a form. But if they arrived from a link (on the same site or another site), then I want the form to show.

I do understand that I may have to use the Javascript referer_url option, but is there any way to hide the form if the visitor has no referer_url value?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by `another site`? Is it owned by you OR are you referring to any site that is linking to your site?

Comment: Can you hide the form? YES! Can you get value of document referrer? YES!... Thus you CAN hide the form if the visitor has no referrer! :)

Comment: CuriousMind, edited the question. I agree with you that "another site" did not explain the question well.     Thank you.Matus, thank you so much. I am a beginner -- can I request you to elaborate a bit more. Thanks again--have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straight forward, if document.referrer has a value show, otherwise hide. This one liner seems to do what you need it to:

```
document.getElementById("theForm").style.display = document.referrer ?  "block" : "none";
```

Comment: Thank you Asinis. The form still shows irrespective of whether the document.referrer exists or not. Here's the code:

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("form1").style.display = document.referrer ?  "block" : "none";
</script>
      
<form action="/js/not_found.php" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">     
-------</form>

Comment: Do you get an error? In any case, the form should be there before the script, otherwise it may not find it.

Comment: Asinux, thank you so much -- adding the form before the script did the trick! Conversely, can I similarly only show another alternative form if the visitor has no referer_url value?